# What Swing component(s) should I use to display a list of songs and song attributes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jlist

I am writing a music player that can play local mp3 files. I am trying to display a list of songs for the user to select and play from, but I am having trouble figuring out what Swing components to use.

### What I am trying to do

- display songs in a list
- in each horizontal row, a song entry is displayed
- in each column, an attribute of each song entry is displayed (track name, length, album, artist)
- above each column is a column header that displays that attribute
- when users click a song entry, it is highlighted
- sort entries by each column (track name, length, album, artist) by clicking on the header
- resizable column widths
- double click an entry to play it
- eventually, artist and album labels should be able to behave like hyperlinks

### Options I have considered

**JTable**: can't highlight an entire row, cells are editable

**JList**: lists are 1 "element" wide so columns and their headers would be hard to set up, not sure about putting a Swing component in the list element

**Lots of JPanels**: putting together lots of JPanels to implement my own display would be very difficult and very messy

I am open to other options I have not thought of and any misconceptions I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re. `JTable`

> can't highlight an entire row,..

Call [`JTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed-boolean-).

> ..cells are editable

Override [`TableModel.isCellEditable(row,col)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable-int-int-).

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks for clearing up my misconceptions there.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **JTable**. A JTable can highlight the entire row, and whether a cell is editable or not is your choice.

You should pass in your own `TableModel` and `TableColumnModel`.

If you are having problems programming a JTable with row selection and no editable cells, you can post a new question with the code you have.

Comment: The JTable will create the TableColumnModel based on the TableModel.

Comment: Yes - and if you implement your own TableModel (that's what I always do), you also have to pass the TableColumn definitions.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt No you don't "have" to (provide your own `ColumnModel`), `TableModel` defines `getColumnCount`, `getColumnClass`, `getColumnName` which `JTable` uses to automatically generate a column model from

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go the pay route you could use something like the [JIDE Grid](http://jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm).  If you want free then either stick with a configured JTable (as previously stated) or look at libraries that give you better UI components like [Insubstantial](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial).

Here's a bunch of [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/Grid-Table.htm) on how to code certain things in tables.